# Scope of variables in recursively called functions

Tags: r

I understand that variables are local to a function in R, but what happens if I recursively call a function from itself? Will assignments from within the function be overwritten by subsequent evocations of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical programming languages, variables created in a function are local to that function. A function calling itself is similar to a function calling another function, as far as the variables created and housed within that function. Soon as that function returns the variables and their association in memory are lost; and unless you use pointers, references, returning variables, etc. you will not be able to retrieve this information, regardless if it's a recursive function.

I am not sure about R in specific, but I would simply create a simple test to see.

Comment: I tested it and you are correct. Scoping is local to recursively called functions.